# Confused with a proof about group solubility

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

I am reading about soluble groups in Ian Stewart's book about Galois theory (fourth edition)
and I came across a theorem which I can not understand the proof of. Down below is the theorem and the proof which can be found in the book mentioned before on page 163:

**Theorem.** *Let $G$ be a group, $H$ a subgroup of $G$, and $N$ a normal subgroup of $G$.*

*(1) If $G$ is soluble, then $H$ is soluble.*

*(2)...*

*Proof.* (1) Let $1 = G_0 \triangleleft G_1 \triangleleft \cdots \triangleleft G_r = G$
be a series for $G$ with abelian quotients $G_{i+1}/G$. Let $H_i = G_i \cap H$. Then $H$ has a series $1 = H_0 \triangleleft \cdots \triangleleft H_r = H.$
We show the quotents are abelian. Now (here is the part that I do not understand)

$\frac{ H_{i+1}}{H_i} = \frac{G_{i+1} \cap H}{G_i \cap H} = \frac{G_{i+1} \cap H}{G_i \cap (G_{i+1} \cap H)} \cong \frac{G_i(G_{i+1} \cap H)}{G_i}$

by the first isomorphism theorem. But this latter group is a subgroup of $G_{i+1}/G_i$ which is abelian. Hence $H_{i+1}/H_i$ is abelian for all $i$, and $H$ is soluble. $\square$

I understand everything in the proof up until the point when Steward mentions the first isomorphism theorem. The first thing that is confusing is the notation $G_i(G_{i+1} \cap H)$, what does this mean? Is this some sort of "group multiplication"? What's confusing me is that there's no symbol between $G_i$ and $(G_{i+1} \cap H)$. I have been self-studying some Galois theory and group theory and I have never come across this notation before.

The second thing that I can not grasp is how $\frac{G_{i+1} \cap H}{G_i \cap (G_{i+1} \cap H)}$ can be isomorphic to $\frac{G_i(G_{i+1} \cap H)}{G_i}$ by the first isomorphism theorem. The first isomorphism theorem states that if $\varphi: G \rightarrow H$ is a homomorphism between two groups then $G/\ker(\varphi) \cong$ im$(\varphi)$. To use this theorem, one first needs an isomorphism between two groups. However, in the proof, there is in my opinion, no clear isomorphism that is equivalent to $\varphi$ so I can not understand how one would use this theorem in this case.

### Edit

Okay so I have been playing around and I think that I am on to something.
First, define the map $\varphi: G_{i+1} \cap H \rightarrow \frac{G_i(G_{i+1} \cap H)}{G_i}$ defined by $\varphi: g_h \mapsto (gg_h)G_i = g_hG_i$ where $g_h \in G_{i+1} \cap H$ and $g \in G_i$. We will now use $g$ and $g_h$ like we did here throughout this part.

Now $\varphi$ is a surjective homomorphism so im$(\varphi) = \frac{G_i(G_{i+1} \cap H)}{G_i}$. Notice that

$\ker(\varphi) = \{g_h \; | \; g_hG_i = G_i\}.$

Since $g_h$, per definition, is an element of $G_{i+1} \cap H$
then $g_h$ must also be an element of $G_i$ and so $g_h \in G_i \cap (G_{i+1} \cap H)$. This shows that $\ker(\varphi) \subseteq G_i \cap (G_{i+1} \cap H).$ By a similar argument, one can show that $G_i \cap (G_{i+1} \cap H) \subseteq \ker(\varphi)$ which means that $\ker(\varphi) = G_i \cap (G_{i+1} \cap H)$. Now, by the first isomorphism theorem, we have our desired isomorphism. Is this correct or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

It is the set product, defined like so: for $K,L\le G$,

$$KL=\{k\ell\in G\mid k\in K,\ell\in L\}.$$

Comment: oh okay! So if $+$ is the binary operation on $G$ then $KL = \{k+l \in G | k \in K, l \in L\}$?

Comment: Precisely, @gabbe1237.